# How to make a circular sprite appear - pygame

Tags: python, class, object, pygame, sprite

I need my sprite to appear in the pygame window. How do I do this? Important code:

```
#This will be a list that will contain all the sprites we intend to use in our game.
    all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()


    #creating the player
    player = player(BLUE, 60, 80, 70)
    player.rect.x = 200
    player.rect.y = 300
```

At the end of the code I have `pygame.display.update()`. My sprite class (correctly imported):

```
class player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color, width, height, speed):
        # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
        super().__init__()

        # Pass in the color of the player, and its x and y position, width and height.
        # Set the background color and set it to be transparent
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(WHITE)
        self.image.set_colorkey(WHITE)

        #Initialise attributes of the car.
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.speed = speed

        # Draw the player
        pygame.draw.circle(self.image, self.color, (400, 600), 5)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
```

Could be a stupid human mistake. I tried replacing `self.rect = self.image.get_rect()` with `self.rect = self.image.get_circle()` as my sprite is circular but this returns:

```
self.rect = self.image.get_circle()
AttributeError: 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'get_circle'
```

Can I have some help please?

Comment: What do you expect? `get_circle()` does not exist. See [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html).  [`get_rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect) returns a rectangle with the width and height of the Surface. The circle is just a buch of pixels on the surface, there is no "circle" object. [`pygame.draw.circle()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.circle) paints some pixels on a Surface, which are arranged to a circular shape.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`get_circle()` does not exist. See [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html).  [`get_rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect) returns a rectangle with the width and height of the Surface. The circle is just a buch of pixels on the surface, there is no "circle" object. [`pygame.draw.circle()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.circle) paints some pixels on a Surface, which are arranged to a circular shape.

You have to center the circle to Surface object `self.image`. The size of the Surface is `(width, height`), thus the center is `(width // 2, height // 2)`:

```py
self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
self.image.fill(WHITE)
self.image.set_colorkey(WHITE)
pygame.draw.circle(self.image, self.color, (width // 2, height // 2), 5)
self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
```

---

Note, since the radius of the circle is 5, it makes no sense to create a surface with a size of 60x80. Further more, I recommend to pass the `x` and `y` coordinate and the `radius` to `player`:

```py
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color, x, y, radius, speed):
        # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
        super().__init__()

        # Pass in the color of the player, and its x and y position, width and height.
        # Set the background color and set it to be transparent
        self.image = pygame.Surface((radius*2, radius*2))
        self.image.fill(WHITE)
        self.image.set_colorkey(WHITE)

        #Initialise attributes of the car.
        self.color = color
        self.speed = speed

        # Draw the player
        pygame.draw.circle(self.image, self.color, (radius, radius), radius)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (x, y))
```

```py
all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

player = Player(BLUE, 200, 300, 5, 70)
all_sprites.add(player)
```

---

Do not use the same name for the class and the instance of the class, because the variable name covers the class name. While [Class Names](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names) should normally use the CapWords convention, [Variable Names](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names) should be lowercase.
So the name of the class is `Player` and the name of the variable (instance) is `player`.